# Convert one sql column into two based on the value from an id column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that is storing values for position and velocity. However, these two values are stored in a single column and identified by an id tag in another row.

```
tagid    value    t_stamp
1        14.5     sometime1
1        13.5     sometime2
2        45.9     sometime1
2        32.8     sometime2
```

In this case, the values that have a tagid of 1 are position and those that have a tagid of 2 are velocity. I want to separate out these two to make a table like this:

```
position    velocity    time 
14.5        45.9        sometime1
13.5        32.8        sometime2
```

I am new to SQL Querying so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `conditional` aggregation here :

```
select max(case when tagid = 1 then value end) as position,
       max(case when tagid = 2 then value end) as velocity, t_stamp as time 
from table t
group by t_stamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN tagid = 1
                 THEN value
             END
           ) AS position,
       MAX( CASE WHEN tagid = 2
            THEN value
             END
           ) AS velocity,     
       t_stamp AS time
  FROM YourTable
GROUP BY t_stamp;
```